# Match/Select from mnesia using prefix

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I have a mnesia table with fields like id, name, city...
I would like to select/match name using prefix, for example if there are multiple records with names starting with "joe" i would like to select all of them efficiently without iterating all the records.

Just like sql query "select id from mytbl where name like joe%". Thanks

**Update:**

Benchmarks based on 1000 records:

MySql(name also a primary key): 450-500 microseconds

Mnesia actual table(not key): 300-370 microseconds

Separate ordered_set mnesia table with name as key: 60-108 microseconds

**Note:** mnesia tables are ram only, i didn't notice any performance difference even after indexing name field for actual table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like:

```
mnesia:select(mytbl, ets:fun2ms(fun(#mytbl{name = "joe" ++ _, id = Id}) -> Id end)).
```

or

```
mnesia:select(mytbl, [{#mytbl{name = "joe" ++ '_', id = '$1', _ = '_'},[],['$1']}]).
```

(That is a [match specification](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/match_spec.html).  The two variants are equivalent, but it's usually clearer to use [`ets:fun2ms`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#fun2ms-1) to generate match specifications.  You'll need `-include_lib("stdlib/include/ms_transform.hrl").` for this to be accepted by the compiler.  Note that if you try this in the shell, only the latter will work, because of [an inconsistency](https://github.com/erlang/otp/pull/2322) in how `++` is handled by `ets:fun2ms`.)

Note that behind the scenes this will *still* iterate through all the records, unless your table is of type `ordered_set` and `name` is the primary key.

---

If you want to get the full record, and not just the `id` field, that would be:

```
mnesia:select(mytbl, ets:fun2ms(fun(#mytbl{name = "joe" ++ _} = X) -> X end)).
```

or

```
mnesia:select(mytbl, [{#mytbl{name = "joe" ++ '_', _ = '_'},[],['$_']}]).
```

Comment: Because it is going to accessed frequently, is it better to create another table as ordered_set with name as key and put some atom or integer as value?

Comment: Also, mnesia tables are populated from mysql, which runs parallel to mnesia as persistent database, how much of performance difference there could be if i query mysql directly instead of mnesia?

Comment: If mysql can use an index for prefix queries like this, I'd definitely try that and see how well it performs. Otherwise a separate ordered_set table might be the way to go.

Comment: Thankyou for your time and effort, i will do some benchmarks and share results.

Comment: For future references, you might have to set Result as '$_' instead of '$1' to get full record including full name that got matched.